# Getting actual size of zip entries

Tags: java, 7zip, zip

I have to analyse zip files to check how large the contents are in it however ZipEntry.getSize() keeps returning -1. This is according to spec if the original size is unknown but for some reason 7-zip does seem to know the actual size as it is shown if I open the zip with it.

Does anyone know how 7-zip does this? Does it simply estimate?

Comment: Perhaps 7-zip expands each entry in RAM to find the inflated size.

Comment: While possible, the speed with which it opens large zips makes this doubtful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe ZipEntry processess only local file headers, instead of central directory which is written at the end of the zip archive after compression is done, and should contain the actual file size information.

Comment: This seems accurate, I have written some code to parse the central directory and the correct sizes are there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, here is the code I used to parse the zips (keep in mind that zip is little endian). I used wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) as a reference for the structure.

```
public static List<ZipCentralFileHeader> getCentralDirectory(File file) throws IOException {
    List<ZipCentralFileHeader> entries = new ArrayList<ZipCentralFileHeader>();
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        // only check the last 10 meg, make sure this is large enough depending on your data
        long sizeToSkip = Math.max(0, file.length() - (1024 * 1024 * 10));
        if (sizeToSkip > 0)
            input.skip(sizeToSkip);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[(int) (file.length() - sizeToSkip)];
        int read = input.read(buffer);
        if (read != buffer.length)
            throw new IOException("Could not read the necessary data");
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length - 4; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == 0x50 && buffer[i + 1] == 0x4b && buffer[i + 2] == 0x01 && buffer[i + 3] == 0x02) {
                Date lastModified = dosToJavaTime(get32(buffer, i + 12));
                long compressedSize = get32(buffer, i + 20);
                long uncompressedSize = get32(buffer, i + 24);
                int nameLength = get16(buffer, i + 28);
                int extraFieldLength = get16(buffer, i + 30);
                int commentLength = get16(buffer, i + 32);

                String fileName = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, i + 46, i + 46 + nameLength), "UTF-8");
                String comment = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, i + 46 + nameLength + extraFieldLength, i + 46 + nameLength + extraFieldLength + commentLength), "UTF-8");

                entries.add(new ZipCentralFileHeader(fileName, lastModified, compressedSize, uncompressedSize, comment));
            }
            // the end of the central directory
            else if (buffer[i] == 0x50 && buffer[i + 1] == 0x4b && buffer[i + 2] == 0x05 && buffer[i + 3] == 0x06) { //0x06054b50
                // each header starts the same, there is no general start sequence for the entire central directory
                // as such you can't really be sure you got them all unless you scan the entire file
                // the trailing section however contains the necessary information to validate the amount
                int amountOfFileHeaders = get16(buffer, i + 8);
                if (amountOfFileHeaders != entries.size())
                    throw new IOException("Could only read " + entries.size() + "/" + amountOfFileHeaders + " headers for " + file + ", you likely did not read enough of the file");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        input.close();
    }
    return entries;
}
```

The utility methods get16, get32, get64 and dosToJavaTime are copies from the existing ZipEntry code based on a snapshot of jdk 7:

```
private static final int get16(byte b[], int off) {
    return (b[off] & 0xff) | ((b[off+1] & 0xff) << 8);
}

private static final long get32(byte b[], int off) {
    return (get16(b, off) | ((long)get16(b, off+2) << 16)) & 0xffffffffL;
}

private static final long get64(byte b[], int off) {
    return get32(b, off) | (get32(b, off+4) << 32);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Date dosToJavaTime(long dtime) {
    Date date = new Date((int)(((dtime >> 25) & 0x7f) + 80),
                      (int)(((dtime >> 21) & 0x0f) - 1),
                      (int)((dtime >> 16) & 0x1f),
                      (int)((dtime >> 11) & 0x1f),
                      (int)((dtime >> 5) & 0x3f),
                      (int)((dtime << 1) & 0x3e));
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Actually zip file contains CentralDirectoryLocator record, which points to the beginning of central directory and number of entries in it. So you should first skip some bytes (up to kilobyte or so) from the end and seak for central dir locator, and after that - seek to the beginning of central dir and read it.